# Reauthenticate user x from an "admin user" to delete user x

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In others Firebase version with removeUser we can delete an user only using email and password. With the new Firebase version it seems you can only delete and user if you have connected with that one... But the problem comes when I am connected with the admin user and I tried to delete the other user. This is the code.

```
    final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

 AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider
  .getCredential(mail, postSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getPwdUser());

 user.reauthenticate(credential)
  .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < Void > () {
   @Override
   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < Void > task) {

    user.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < Void > () {
     @Override
     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < Void > taskDeleted) {
      if (taskDeleted.isSuccessful()) {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "Deleted user!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
     }
    });
   }
  });
```

But I can't get delete method because on reauthenticate it throws an error with "The supplied credentials do not correspond to the previously signed in user." Anyone knows how I can reauthenticate from another user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the code should be something like this

```
 mAuth.signOut();
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(UserList.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    mAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance(myFirebaseRef.getDatabase().getApp());
                    try{

                        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(getsPreferences().getString("mailUser",""), getsPreferences().getString("pwd",""))
                                .addOnCompleteListener(UserList.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                                    }});
                    }catch(Exception e){

                    }
                }
            }});
```

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase SDK for Android can only delete the currently logged in user. So if you know the user's email+password, you'll have to sign in as that user to delete the account.

For admin functionality you should use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), which you should run on a trusted back-end server. Authentication functionality currently is only available in the [Firebase Admin SDK for Node](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users).

Comment: Finally the solution was signout from the actual user, and after signwitheamilAndPassword , with the user and password known, delete de logged user and after login with the admin user.